# get query from Zend Request object

Tags: zend-framework

Can anyone tell me why the result from this

```
$month = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('month');
```

is an empty string

The call is made from my blogcontroller class which extends Zend_Controller_Action

the URL: htp://www.domain.nl/blogmanager/?month=2005-01

could it be my htaccess?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
DirectoryIndex index.php 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
```

**EDIT:** solved it, I had to remove the questionmark from the rewriterule

Comment: I answerd my own question, how can I ever close this question now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Or

```
$month = $this->getRequest()->getParam('month');
```

Comment: it's blogmanager I follow the book example web.2.0 applications

Comment: this is weird, I can see the url and a simple  get['month'] will not work

Comment: shouldnt your url be like: htp://www.domain.nl/blogmanager/month/2005-01 ...?

Comment: it doesn't have to, not according to the book